# Problema al realizar un test unitario

Tags: java, pruebas-unitarias, junit

Buenas lo que pretendo es hacer un método que al hacer una transferencia de una cuenta a otra pueda actualizar las dos en caso de que la transacción haya sido aceptada, tengo el siguiente test en junit

```
@Test
public void TransferenciaTest(){
    final Cuenta otracuenta = new Cuenta("Otra cuenta", "2311", 3, 4000);
    double haztransferencia = otracuenta.transferencia("ingresodavid", 2000);
    assertEquals(2000, haztransferencia, 0);
}
```

Y la clase a la que hace referencia es la siguiente.

```
package Com.example;

public class Cuenta {
    public String nombre_cliente, numero_cuenta;
    public double tipo_interes, saldo;

    public Cuenta(){
    }

    public Cuenta(String nombre_cliente, String numero_cuenta, double tipo_interes, double saldo){
        this.nombre_cliente = nombre_cliente;
        this.numero_cuenta = numero_cuenta;
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.tipo_interes = tipo_interes;
    }

    public String getNombre_cliente() {
        return nombre_cliente;
    }

    public void setNombre_cliente(String nombre_cliente) {
        this.nombre_cliente = nombre_cliente;
    }

    public String getNumero_cuenta() {
        return numero_cuenta;
    }

    public void setNumero_cuenta(String numero_cuenta) {
        this.numero_cuenta = numero_cuenta;
    }

    public double getTipo_interes() {
        return tipo_interes;
    }

    public void setTipo_interes(double tipo_interes) {
        this.tipo_interes = tipo_interes;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    public boolean ingreso(double cantidad_ingreso){
        boolean ingresoCorrecto = false;
        ingresoCorrecto = (cantidad_ingreso >= 0);
        if (ingresoCorrecto){
            double saldo_anterior = getSaldo();
            double actualizar_datos = saldo_anterior + cantidad_ingreso;
            setSaldo(actualizar_datos);
        }
        return ingresoCorrecto;
    }

    public boolean reintegro(double cantidad_reintegro){
        boolean reintegroCorrecto = false;
        reintegroCorrecto = (cantidad_reintegro > 0) && ((getSaldo() - cantidad_reintegro) >= 0);
        System.out.println(reintegroCorrecto);
        return reintegroCorrecto;
    }

    public double transferencia(Cuenta cuentadeIngreso, double cantidadTransferencia){
        boolean haztransferencia = false;
        double descuento, totalDespuesTransferencia;
        haztransferencia = getSaldo() - cantidadTransferencia >= 0;
        if (haztransferencia){
            descuento = getSaldo() - cantidadTransferencia;
            cuentadeIngreso.ingreso(cantidadTransferencia);
            setSaldo(descuento);
        }
        return getSaldo() + cuentadeIngreso.getSaldo();
    }
}
```

El problema es que me lo marca en rojo y no entiendo muy bien por que en las opciones que intellij me da es Error:(46, 60) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to Com.example.Cuenta pero si en el método transferencia el parámetro pongo string no me hace lo que yo quiero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como lo tienes implementado, la transferencia se hace de una cuenta a otra, por tanto tienes que crear dos cuentas, la de origen y la de destino, y pasar la de destino como parámetro a la de origen:

```
@Test
public void TransferenciaTest(){
    final Cuenta unaCuenta = new Cuenta("Mi cuenta", "0001", 3, 1000);
    final Cuenta otracuenta = new Cuenta("Otra cuenta", "2311", 3, 4000);
    double haztransferencia = otracuenta.transferencia(unaCuenta, "ingresodavid", 2000);
    assertEquals(2000, haztransferencia, 0);
}
```

Comment: La tengo creada en el inicio de la clase test                                              public class CuentaTest {
    private final Cuenta ingresodavid = new Cuenta("Jose David", "2616", 2, 300);

Comment: Pero no la has pasado como parámetro al método `.transferencia`

Comment: Gracias no veia el fallo :)